# Can I Toggle Grass

Tags: rust

I used to play rust loads during the legacy days and have just recently got back into playing this updated version of the game I remember being able to toggle the grass in the old game and this was useful to help stop lagging but the command doesn't work in the new version

Is there a way I can toggle the grass in the New version of Rust

**Edit**

The Command I have tried was

`grass.on False`

Worked fine in legacy version and doesn't work in new version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rust is currently in Alpha stage and hence updates come in on daily basis. 'grass.on "true/false"' console command still works. There was a brief time when the command stopped responding.

If the above command fails, press F1 and open console

and type grass.quality 0.(this command helps to improve fps spikes coming from grass)

**remember that sometimes you have to enter the command twice**